# How do I generate a report with Vanity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ab-testing, vanity

Whenever I try to generate a report with Vanity, it creates an empty HTML file

```
>vanity report --output vanity.html
Vanity: loading experiments from ...
Vanity: loading metrics from ...
New report available in vanity.html
```

When viewing in the browser

> Vanity's cached experiments are out of sync with those on the filesystem and/or those in the datastore. Please restart your server and/or turn on collecting.

I've already restarted the server several times, and ran through the the registration process several times.

```
>rails server
Vanity: loading experiments from C:/.../experiments
Vanity: loading metrics from C:/.../experiments/metrics
[2014-03-14 04:53:34] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
```

I was able to load the experiment page and see both color options. I have the `track!` code.

```
  if @user.save(validate: false)
    track! :register # Vanity
```

I even see the values in Redis

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
 1) "vanity:experiments:color_options:outcome"
 2) "vanity:experiments:color_options:created_at"
 3) "vanity:experiments:landing_page:alts:0:conversions"
 4) "vanity:metrics:register:last_update_at"
 5) "vanity:metrics:register:2014-03-14:value:0"
 6) "scores"
 7) "vanity:experiments:color_options:completed_at"
 8) "vanity:experiments:color_options:alts:0:conversions"
10) "vanity:experiments:color_options:alts:1:conversions"
11) "vanity:experiments:color_options:alts:0:participants"
14) "vanity:experiments:color_options:alts:1:converted"
15) "vanity:experiments:color_options:alts:1:participants"
16) "vanity:experiments:landing_page:created_at"
```

I even added `model User` to the metric, because it claimed to look at existing historical data.

```
metric "Registration" do
  description "Measures how many people signed up for our awesome service."
  model User
end
```

Reference http://vanity.labnotes.org/

Comment: What rails environment are you doing this in?

Comment: Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

@chloe this was a bug and closed in [a3cc4f7](https://github.com/assaf/vanity/commit/a3cc4f79b837fb8a954d8cc26734094728b1af43). It's been merged into the master branch and will be in the upcoming 1.9.1 release.